# EBNF Colon and Semicolon usage?

Tags: bnf, ebnf

I have no idea what a colon means in BNF or EBNF. It's not listed anywhere on the internet. Anyway, my professor decided to assign it in the homework. I think he is confusing it with a semicolon or something. I'm still not even sure what the semicolon means. Here is some context:

Given the following CFG (context free grammar) for declarations:

```
D -> D ; D
D -> id : T
T -> char
T -> integer
```

Give an attribute grammar that defines type of an identifier (id stands for identifier).

Anyone think they can help?

Comment: I think its suppose to be a ; is suppose to be some operator. That just means. D can be T where t can be -> identifier or char/integer.

Answer (score 1):

`;` and `:` are simply terminals, just like `id`, `char` and `integer`. So your code could be something like this:

```
x : char ; y : integer ; z : char
```